# php process image files created with complicated url syntax

Tags: php

I have a script on my server that dynamically creates images of chess diagrams:

```
<img src = "ChessImager/ChessImager.php?fen=r3k2r/1pqb2pp/pnn2p2/4p3/4Q3/NBP1B3/P4PPP/R2R2K1&amp;square_size=45&amp;ds_color=(143,188,143)&amp;ls_color=(232,223,192)">
```

But the resulting image files are nearly 30k, too big. I want to use pngnq http://pngnq.sourceforge.net/ to shrink them. I present them in a slideshow at http://communitychessclub.com I want a new php script to create the images from ChessImager.php and pipe each of these diagram image files (~50) to a new filename like 'game1234.png' and I'll batch pre-process (not real-time) them with pngnq. I have a file 'Forsyth.csv' which lists the data:

r1bqk2r/1p2bp1p/p2pnp2/4pN1Q/2B1P3/2N5/PP3PPP/R2R2K1|1256
r3k2r/1pqb2pp/pnn2p2/4p3/4Q3/NBP1B3/P4PPP/R2R2K1|1255
4rrk1/ppp3pp/2n4q/3p4/3P4/1NP1PpPP/PP3Q1K/R4R2|1253
rn2kb1r/1q1p2p1/p3p3/1p2N1Bp/2p1P2P/2P4Q/PP3PP1/3R1RK1|1252

I use this:

```
<?php $text = file('Forsyth.csv');foreach($text as $line) 
{$token = explode("|", $line); print "\n"; $fen = $token[0]; $game_num = $token[1];
$phrase="games/game$game_num.php"; echo "<li> <img 
src=\"ChessImager/ChessImager.php?fen=$fen&amp;square_size=45&amp;ds_color=(143,188,143)&amp;ls_color=(232,223,192)\" ></li>";} ?>
```

Any ideas?

Update: this is posted at http://communitychessclub.com/produce.php

```
<?php $text = file('Forsyth.csv'); foreach($text as $line) {$token = explode("|",
$line); print "\n"; $fen = $token[0]; $game_num = $token[1]; print "\n";
$goat = "diagrams/game$game_num.png"; 
$src="ChessImager/ChessImager.php?fen=$fen&amp;square_size=45&amp;ds_color=(143,188,143)&amp;ls_color=(232,223,192)";
echo "<li><img src = \"$src\"></li>";}
?>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Kewl concept.  Have you considered using an animated GIF?

Comment: No, image has to be clickable URL link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChesssImager.php or one of its includes must have a `imagepng($image)` line near the end that sends the generated PNG image to the web browser. If your question is how to save that data to the disk instead, you can just modify the script so that it saves the image data instead:

```
imagepng($image, $filename);
```

where $filename is something unique that you can generate from the arguments passed to the script. For example:

```
$filename = md5($fen).".png";
```

Wherever you decide to have the script save the files, you'll need to make sure that you (or the web server if you're running it in a browser) has permission to write to that folder.

Comment: http://communitychessclub.com/ChessImager/ChessImagerUtils.txt is the php file renamed. The problem is that the line #19 to edit from:     imagePNG($img);
//imagePNG($img, $goat); is probably not right based the php code I see. Also I will edit the original post to show current php file. Please see it. Thank you.

Comment: imagePNG($img, $goat) will attempt to save the PNG to a file named by the value of the $goat variable. You can change the filename to whatever you like. If the filename doesn't matter you can use something like [`tempnam()`](http://us2.php.net/tempnam) to make the filename for you e.g. `imagePNG($img, tempname("."))`. If the filename matters, then the trick will be to rework the code so that the right information is available to `sendImage()` to generate an appropriate name.

Comment: $goat = "/public_html/diagrams/game$game_num.png"; It dw. I'm in over my head. Thank you, though!

Comment: Well before I  give up, is there a way to use wget or cURL to get the files and process them locally? I think the URL syntax is so convoluted that wget or cURL would barf.

Comment: wget or curl can fetch those URLs just fine. Enclose the urls in quotes: `wget "big-ugly-chessimager-url"`

Comment: Incredible! You are 100% correct! Thank you so much. This will enable me to batch process the diagrams effortlessly. I was using gimp save for web plugin which was cumbersome and took a long time.